Android .xlsx to .pdf convertation
Возникла задача, с сервера приходит Base64 строка, в которой Excel файл (точнее его содержимое). Нужно отобразить эти данные на екране, и в дальнейшем отправить на принтер. Мой поход в google поиск нашел несколько подсказок
implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3")
implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3")
implementation("org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:3.0.0")
implementation("com.tom-roush:pdfbox-android:2.0.0.0")

Вот такой набор библиотек, но почему-то последняя не компилируется, в консоли пусто, мы в GPT не смогли определить причину.
implementation("com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.13.2")

По документации просто дает возможность самостоятельно нарисовать данные. Но моя проблема заключается в том, что файлин не просто таблица, а важно сохранять форматирование, размеры шрифта, и прочие атрибуты. Возможно есть достойное решение, которое я не смогу найти, буду благодарен за подсказку!

Достойное решение -- делать все это на сервере. Скачивать PDF и дальше уже стандартными средствами ОС.
